# Can i drive my 2016 Jeep Grand Cherokee 100 miles to a mechanic with a misfiring cylinder?

Tags: engine, jeep, misfire, grand-cherokee

My 2016 Jeep Grand Cherokee started hesitating when accelerating, but only after the engine warms up. The testing tool says it's a cylinder 2 misfire. The mechanic I want to take it to is 100 miles away...is it safe to drive it there, or will that cause any damage?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

You will not cause any damage to the vehicle **except you'd need to disconnect the fuel injector wiring on the misfiring cylinder**. If you do not do this, you'll be pouring unburnt fuel into that cylinder for the whole trip. This will get in your oil thinning it out which if bad enough could cause internal damage to the engine due to lack of lubrication. The excess fuel will also pass through to the catalytic converter which will become super hot trying to burn off the unburnt fuel. This will not only damage your catalytic converter, it could also potentially start a fire in your car.

**If you do not know which cylinder is misfiring or how to disconnect the fuel injector, I'd suggest you have it towed.**